# HDMI-CEC and the Chromecast

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast, hdmi

I know that the Chromecast is being launched automatically with any app that has the "Cast" icon. That means we can be using directly a phone or tablet without the TV controller to initiate a connection.
HDMI-CEC has something to do with this.
TV switches automatically.

**What I would like to know is if it would be possible to end the connection with the Chromecast and not land on the Chromecast homepage like right now.** I would like to come back on the signal that I had before the "Cast", which could be a channel of the TV for example, and this, without the TV controller.
Currently, it is impossible to come back without not using the "Source" button of the TV controller.

Does anyone have a solution that could help me?

Answer (score 1):

So, in CEC there is a provision to tell the TV you're done. It's called `<Inactive Source>`.

Chromecast uses `<Active Source>` to turn on the TV and change inputs it it.

It could use `<Inactive Source>` to indicate to the TV that it has stopped sending video.

`<Inactive Source>`, however, varies by TV.

Comment: Can you rewrite your second and third sentence? As they are written now it is hard to understand what you are saying (not trying to be mean). Also please don't add your signature to any posts you are writing http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior